# how to make product with attribute which select admin and only this attributes be visible for user

Tags: 7, commerce

So i for example:
i have a commerce_product, in this product there is attributes (select list or check-boxes)

attribute: **[color white]**

attribute: **[color red]**

attribute: **[color pink]**

attribute: **[color black]**

attribute: **[color green]**

attribute: **[color orange]**

when admin select only pink, green and red, these attributes must showing for user, without [black], [orange] and [white] attributes, in select list...

How it's can make? (without multiply commerce product)
price not change if user selects black or other attributes

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You should create a **Vocabulary** : **Color** . In the voacabulary list all terms with the list of colors: blue, red , green etc 
. In your Product Display field add a Term Reference field and include vocabulary color to the product display.
For Red Shirt you should select the color Red  in term reference field autocomplete or checkbox.
Similarly for other colors you should do the same.

Comment: Thanks for reply))
But i need this in product-commerce not in a node-type...
because, in node-product-display i have 'Product reference' unlimited for different size, and when select size, must shows colors which select admin, but only one color user can choose